# How to put single quotes to the onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, quotes

My code is here 
printNextPeriod(new Date(2019-01-01), new Date(2020-01-01),26);
Need to put single quotes between dates

expecting like

```
printNextPeriod(new Date('2019-01-01'), new Date('2020-01-01'),26);
```

Where i need to fix this error from the below code?

```
 if (data == 'pestcontrol') {
return ('<button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date('+row["first_job_dt"]+'), new Date('+row["end_date"]+'),'+row["day_bw_job"]+');" data-jobdays="'+ row["day_bw_job"] +'" data-fjd="'+ row["first_job_dt"] +'" data-actiendcontr="'+ row["end_date"] +'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">View Schedule-P</button>');
    }
```

these code within the datatable

```
{
                  "data" : "pest_or_clean", 
                  "bSortable": false,
                   render: function (data, type, row, rowData) {
                  //console.log(data);
                  if (data == 'pestcontrol') {
                  return ('<button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date('+row["first_job_dt"]+'), new Date('+row["end_date"]+'),'+row["day_bw_job"]+');" data-jobdays="'+ row["day_bw_job"] +'" data-fjd="'+ row["first_job_dt"] +'" data-actiendcontr="'+ row["end_date"] +'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">View Schedule-P</button>');
                  } 
                  else {
                  return ('<button data-jobdays="'+ row["day_bw_job"] +'" data-fjd="'+ row["first_job_dt"] +'" data-actiendcontr="'+ row["end_date"] +'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm actclean" data-target="#viewacticleanmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">View Schedule-C</button>');
                  }
                 }
              }
```

Comment: Use `addEventListener` instead, and you won't ever have to worry about these annoying escape issues

Comment: @CertainPerformance how to fix this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use escaped quotes.

```
if (data == 'pestcontrol') {
  return ('<button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date(\''+row["first_job_dt"]+'\'), new Date(\''+row["end_date"]+'\'),'+row["day_bw_job"]+');" data-jobdays="'+ row["day_bw_job"] +'" data-fjd="'+ row["first_job_dt"] +'" data-actiendcontr="'+ row["end_date"] +'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">View Schedule-P</button>');
}
```

It's even simpler if you use ES6 template literals. Also, when the property name in an object is a literal, you can write `variable.prop` instead of the more verbose `variable["prop"]`.

```
if (data == 'pestcontrol') {
  return (`<button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date('${row.first_job_dt}'), new Date('${row.end_date}'),${row.day_bw_job}');" data-jobdays="${row.day_bw_job}" data-fjd="${row.first_job_dt}" data-actiendcontr="${row.end_date}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">View Schedule-P</button>`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)? These are really nice. Since they are enclosed by back-ticks(``` `` ```), you don't run into the single/double quote issue that you're facing.

Template Literals can also contain placeholders, and these are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (`${expression}`).

- No more messy `'string' + variable + 'string'`
- Instead, you can do this `` `string ${variable} string` ``

Check out the snippet below where I threw in some fictional dates in an object to pass to the function.

**Of course, the only caveat is that these are part of the ES6 spec and cannot be used with Internet Explorer** https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

If you must use IE, then you will need to escape the single quote that is actually a part of the string, with a back-slash (`\`) like this:
`'(new Date(\''+row["first_job_dt"]+'\')'`

```js
var row = {
  first_job_dt: `2019-01-01`,
  end_date: `2019-12-31`,
  day_bw_job: `2019-07-07`,
  first_job_dt: `2019-05-01`,
}

function test(data) {
  if (data == `pestcontrol`) {
    return (`<button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date(${row["first_job_dt"]}), new Date(${row["end_date"]}),${row["day_bw_job"]}');" data-jobdays="${row["day_bw_job"]}" data-fjd="${row["first_job_dt"]}" data-actiendcontr="${row["end_date"]}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">View Schedule-P</button>`);
  } else {
    return (`<button data-jobdays="${row["day_bw_job"]}" data-fjd="${row["first_job_dt"]}" data-actiendcontr="${row["end_date"]}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm actclean" data-target="#viewacticleanmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">View Schedule-C</button>`);
  }
}

console.log(test(`pestcontrol`));

console.log(test(`otherValue`));
```